# Check if value exists in a mongodb array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

How to check if current `Meteor.user()._id` exists in `"favoritedBy"` array?

If true, print `"Your favorite"`, if false, print `"Not your favorite"`.

Document in MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id" : "W5WwAZatorDEb6DNP",
  "createdBy" : "aTmb64zNGSyeDYFJZ",
  "favoritedBy" : [ 
      "X594baqWYZiJqA3Qg",
      "fgk234m2dkD229d12"
  ]
}
```

Say that `Meteor.user()._id` returns `X594baqWYZiJqA3Qg`.

How can I do a true/false check on this?

I tried the following:

```
isFavorite: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user()._id;
    return Posts.find({favoritedBy: user});
 }
```

In the template:

```
{{#if isFavorite}}
    Your favorite
{{else}}
    Not your favorite
{{/if}}
```

But it don't seem to work, as it always return as `"Your favorite"`, even if current Meteor user id is not in the array.

Any ideas?

Comment: The reason why your implementation is always returning `"Your favorite"` is because the `isFavorite` method always returns a cursor. This cursor does not immediately access the database or return documents unless if you immediatley call the `fetch()` method which will return all matching documents as an Array or the `count()` method which returns the number of documents that match a query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
isFavorite: function() {
    var user = Meteor.user()._id;
    return Posts.find({favoritedBy: user}).count() > 0 ? true : false;
 }
```

`count()` will returns the count of documents that would match a find() query then check if its `> 0` , and by using [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), if yes it will return `true` if not it will return `false`